# Semilinear elliptic equation $\Delta u = P(u)$ with $P$ being polynomial of degree 3

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-equations

Suppose that $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $P(u)$ is a polynomial with degree 3. If $u \in W^{1,2}(B_1)$ is a weak solution of  $$\Delta u = P(u) \text{  in  } B_1,$$
then can we obtain the smoothness of the solution?

I found that the theories in Trudinger's book can not be applied since the integrability of $P(u)$ is not good enough. And If the degree of $P$ is higher, I found there may not exist a smooth solution.

Is that true if I replace $P(u)$ by a smooth function $g(u)$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{g}{u^3}<\infty$? May I have a reference of it? Thank you!

Comment: If $u\in W^{1,2}$ then by embeddings $u\in L^6$, thus $P(u)\in L^2$. Then you get $u\in H^2_{loc}$. What do you want to obtain here?

Comment: Then we can embed $H^2$ into $C^{0, \alpha}$ and thus $\Delta u \in C^{0, \alpha }$. Therefore, we have $u \in C^{2, \alpha}$. Is it correct?